# Phaser Definitions for typescript not being read by VSCode

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, phaser-framework

I've been following [this tutorial](http://www.photonstorm.com/phaser/how-to-use-phaser-with-typescript) for phaser, but I've been unable to run the code in item 4. I've copied it exactly with no modifications (see below, if you haven't already seen the tutorial), but I'm running into errors.

The line `new Phaser.Game(800, 600, Phaser.AUTO, 'content', { preload: this.preload, create: this.create });` is giving me the error "[ts] expected 0-1 arguments, got 5," and I'm also being told that the properties "load," "add" and "world" don't exist for the type "Game."

When attempting to compile, I'm given this response.

```
    TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
app.ts(4,25): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Phaser'.
app.ts(4,47): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Phaser'.
app.ts(7,11): error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'Phaser'.

    at createTSError (C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:261:12)
    at getOutput (C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:367:40)
    at Object.compile (C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:558:11)
    at Module.m._compile (C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:439:43)
    at Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .ts] (C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:442:12)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
```

My app.ts right now:

```
class SimpleGame {

    constructor() {
        this.game = new Phaser.Game(800, 600, Phaser.AUTO, 'content', { preload: this.preload, create: this.create });
    }

    game: Phaser.Game;

    preload() {
        this.game.load.image('logo', 'phaser2.png');
    }

    create() {
        var logo = this.game.add.sprite(this.game.world.centerX, this.game.world.centerY, 'logo');
        logo.anchor.setTo(0.5, 0.5);
    }

}

window.onload = () => {

    var game = new SimpleGame();

};
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the example code in the TypeScript tutorial is out of date for Phaser 3.  See [the current example JavaScript code](http://phaser.io/tutorials/getting-started-phaser3/part5).  [The current TypeScript tutorial](http://phaser.io/tutorials/how-to-use-phaser-with-typescript) is out of date too.  Consider using one of Phaser's support channels to report the problem.  In the meantime, you can base your TypeScript code on the JavaScript example.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add reference to your definitions file. Put this to the beginning of your app.ts

```
/// <reference path="path/to/your/deffile/phaser.d.ts" />
```

Also, do not forget to add Pixi definitions.